# Local npm registry, can't create team or org (verdaccio)

Tags: node.js, npm, local, verdaccio

There is a server in which we configured a fresh installation of verdaccio to manage a local cache of NPM packages. We need to give some specific users access to publish packages and also manage package access for other users. For publishing purpose we create a team, put our package publisher users in that team and finally give admin permissions to the team.

The problem is for creating a team, there should exist an org, and there is no documentation for creating an organization via command-line.

Tried below steps

```
npm team create publishers
```

> ```
> npm ERR! code EINVALIDTYPE
> npm ERR! typeerror Error: Argument #1: Expected string but got null
> npm ERR! typeerror at /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/libnpmteam/index.js:20:5
> npm ERR! typeerror at /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/libnpmteam/index.js:104:5
> ...
> npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
> npm ERR! typeerror <https://npm.community>
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-01T04_49_13_414Z-debug.log
> ```

```
npm team create admin:publishers
```

> ```
> npm ERR! code E404
> npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT http://localhost:4873/-/org/admin/team
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-01T04_49_04_772Z-debug.log
> ```

Links already read: [npm team](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/team) - [npm org](https://docs.npmjs.com/orgs/) - [verdaccio](https://verdaccio.org/docs/en/authentification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verdaccio does not support `npm team` and any organization feature created by *npmjs*. You can find https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio#compatibility here the list of commands you can use.

If you want to support those commands by your own, you might create a plugin middleware for it.